# Share service between activities and the new android guidelines to deprecate unbounded backgound services

Tags: android, android-service, android-service-binding, android-7.0-nougat

In [Android battery and memory optimizations - Google I/O 2016](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VC2Hlb22mZM&list=PLOU2XLYxmsILe6_eGvDN3GyiodoV3qNSC&index=27) (at 18:46 aprox) it explains that unbound background services aren't going to work in the future.

I understand the spirit of that changes to preserve user battery and make the phone responsive and performant.

But I've one use case that in spirit is a bounded service but I implement it with an unbounded one.

The use case is a service that is "bound to several activities" and it can be destroyed when the activities are not in foreground but it has to be preserved between activity transitions. (For example a service that maintains some shared state and resources that are the same for all activities and it's not nice to recreate it).

The way I implement it is starting the service as unbound on each activity, then bind to it and make the service track if it has someone binded and if not autodestroy it after some small grace time.

Has someone any idea of how to improve the implementation of that use case without unbounded services?
Or know if some additions to services will be added in the future to allow that use pattern without using unbounded service?

Comment: cannot you just `bindService` (with no prior `startService`) and keep state & resources in a custom `ContentProvider`?

Comment: Thanks @pskink, it's an alternative. But I really doesn't like to mix ContentProviders here. I will prefer to temporary store service state between service creation in the application.
What I don't like about CP is to have to implement one if I don't need/want it, and also that it's lifecycle to my understand is the live of the process.

Comment: `"I will prefer to temporary store service state between service creation in the application"` you mean a custom `android.app.Application` class? it has the same lifecycle as your custom `ContentProvider`: it is destroyed after your process dies

Comment: That's true @psking. What I wanted to expose is that as CP doesn't solve the lifecycle issue I prefer to just use Application and save me to implement the CP. In each of the cases, some timed clear logic will be needed if the state has to be cleared when no activity is bound to the service.

Comment: Why isn't this just a singleton?

Comment: or even static data in your `Service` as an alternative to singleton / custom `Application` class ?

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare Simple is better and you make me think that as I've foreground activities running service isn't needed and it makes all simpler without the need to implement service and manage the async binding lifecycle.
I auto responded the question with more details.

Answer (score 0):

The point from @CommonsWare about just using a singleton is a good point.
Almost always simply is better, and as other solutions add more complexity and doesn't solve lifecycle issues per se I've taken @CommonsWare idea.

At the end the other ideas offer more complexity that isn't needed because as we've activities in foreground we don't need to explicity use a service to indicate that some job is done in background.

The solution I've made is use a countreferenced singleton that tracks if some activity uses the service and when no one uses the "service" for some time it is destroyed.

I [created a Gist if some is interested in the code](https://gist.github.com/lujop/9f29c0028d6800328d1ac0a11844c5bf). Any comments about the implementation are welccomed.